# How to convert a folder into an exe file?

Tags: file, compression, directory, extract, exe

I have an .exe file and I had extracted it by using universal extractor. Now I want to compress all these files (Which I had extracted before) into a .exe file. i.e in the form in which they were before. Please Help me for this.? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can download converter from [here](https://code.google.com/p/convert-folder-into-executable/), and then convert them to .exe file.